# how to use SharePoint to manage work items (tasks)

Tags: windows-server-2008, sharepoint-2007

I am using SharePoint 2007 Enterprise + Publishing portal template + Windows Server 2008. I want to utilize SharePoint to manage work items and I want to let gurus here to recommend me some good tutorials for newbie like me for this field (better through configuration ways, not through coding).

My requirements are,

1. Manager could assign task to workers, and manager could edit task description, due date;
2. Workers could see the tasks assigned to them, and could update task execution status (may attach some documents);
3. Manager could review all tasks assigned by the manager, and updates by workers;
4. Better to have a calendar view with the tasks.

thanks in advance,
George

Comment: Do you use WSS or MOSS?

Comment: MOSS 2007, any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

That's pretty much the functionality that SharePoint task lists provide... The Office site has a number of articles that walk you through this (including how to attach task lists to Outlook or My sites):  http://www.bing.com/search?q=site%3Aoffice.microsoft.com+sharepoint+tasks